# Is possible to get a approximate lat and long from a slightly wrong address using geocoding?

Tags: android, geocoding

I am using a geocoding API in my Android application. I have to find the `latitude` and `longitude` from the address but for some of the address I am not getting any `latitude` and `longitude`. Is there any possibility to get the approximate `latitude` and `longitude` from a slightly wrong address?

For better understanding have a look at my code, I am getting IOException because `geocoder.getFromLocationName(locationAddress, 1)` is returning null:

Here is my code:

```
public  void getAddressFromLocation(final String locationAddress,
                                                  final Context context, final Handler handler) {
            Thread thread = new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
                    String result = null;
                   // String latlong="";
                    try {
                        List addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(locationAddress, 1);
                        if (addressList != null && addressList.size() > 0) {
                            Address address = (Address) addressList.get(0);
                            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                            sb.append(address.getLatitude()).append("_");
                            sb.append(address.getLongitude());
                            result = sb.toString();
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {

                    }

}
```

I am passing this `879 manania road kapuni kapuni 4851` it giving null. If I am giving in`manania road kapuni kapuni 4851` it working, my point is `geocoder` should automatically find the approx `lat` and `long`.

Comment: I am not sure this is exactly you r looking for.. i had the same situation I have used Geocoder.getFromLocationName() if it didn't work I made Rest api call to http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + address + "ka&sensor=false" to get latitude and longitude.

Comment: @Raghavendra you correctly catch my point ,BTW how did you called  maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="; + address + "ka&sensor=false" can you show me.

Comment: I have used asyntask and onResponse u'll get json parse it to get the lat and lng. Check [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#GeocodingResponses)

Comment: @Raghavendra can i use any portal to get the geocode response just before implementing for testing only

Comment: just hit this http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=vidhanasouda,bangalore,ka&sensor=false"

Comment: I found it doing the same what the method Geocoder.getFromLocationName() is doing.

Comment: Please pass 879 manania road kapuni kapuni 4851 in the address as parameter you will a null response.

Comment: Yes but try this http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=879,manania%20road,kapunika&sensor=false

Comment: http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=879,manania%20road,kapunika&sensor=false how this is going this way 879,manania%20road,kapuni but we are sending 879 manania road kapuni kapuni 4851

Comment: No I just passed only that much and tried:)

Comment: you didnt pass the address which i have given thats why  your getting some result the actual address is 879 manania road kapuni kapuni 4851,but you are sending 879 manania road kapuni

Comment: you can try setting a bounding box when calling [geocoder.getFromLocationName](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocationName(java.lang.String,%20int,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20double)), which should make address predictions more accurate. Here's a [great class](http://janmatuschek.de/LatitudeLongitudeBoundingCoordinates#GeoLocationClass) to import into your project that does the bounding box calculations for you. No need to use Google Places/Geocode API directly

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Make a Rest Api(HttpGet) call I have used asyntask. I'll get json response and parse it to get lat and lng

```
public LatLng getLatLng(JSONObject jsonObject) {

        Double lon = new Double(0);
        Double lat = new Double(0);

        try {

            lon = ((JSONArray) jsonObject.get("results")).getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getDouble("lng");

            lat = ((JSONArray) jsonObject.get("results")).getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getDouble("lat");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return new LatLng(lat, lon);
    }

 class GetLatLngTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject>{

        String address = null;
        String name = null;
        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... address) {
            strCompleteAddress = address[0];
            name = address[1];
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + address+ "ka&sensor=false");

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response;
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            try {
                response = client.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
                int b;
                while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
                    stringBuilder.append((char) b);
                }
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            try {
                jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return jsonObject;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonObject) {
            super.onPostExecute(jsonObject);
            LatLng latLng = getLatLng(jsonObject);
}
}
```

You have latnLng in onPostExecute.

Comment: please pass the 879 manania road kapuni kapuni 4851 see if you are getting response

Comment: In the code you are sending the wrong url it should http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address= address""+ka&sensor=false but  you are sending "http://maps.google." + "com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + address+ "ka&sensor=false

Answer (score 0):

The way I handled this was to use [Googles AutoComplete API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete#place_autocomplete_requests) which you can query while the user is typing. A list of addresses will be shown based on what is typed in.

The user can then see a list of valid addresses to pick from, or they can see that what ever they typed it returned 0 addresses so they need to check what they typed in.

When the user clicks one of the valid addresses, you can then geocode the address using what ever service you want.

Comment: @AbhijitChakra I though you said that an incorrect address was being passed in?